# How can I dock a specific System Settings as an icon to the Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher

I need to access my sound settings frequently and thus would like to add a direct shortcut icon to the sound settings to the Unity launcher.

Is there any way to achieve this?

*Unity launcher:*

[image]

*Sound settings icon:*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon you show in your question usually is not presenting itself too obviously; the sound settings usually appear in System Settings > Sound.

You can however navigate to `/usr/share/applications` and drag the file `unity-sound-panel.desktop` on to the launcher, or, open Dash and type "Sound" (or a localized name) to the launcher.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open up your sound settings, the icon for it should appear in the launcher.

Then simply right click on icon > Lock to Launcher